# Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли поставлена запятая в первом предложении? И, если возможно, поясните ответ

Tags: запятые

– Она собиралась держать тебя там, пока какое дитя не родится? До второго пришествия Христа?

Answer (score 2):

Контекста нет, но само предложение выглядит странно. Почему-то хочется использовать цитату:

— *Она собиралась держать тебя там, (до тех пор) пока "**какое дитя не родится**"? До второго пришествия Христа?*

Запятая ставится в СПП с придаточным **времени**, союз ПОКА.

Или надо что-то еще **менять** в грамматике, если смысл такой: ..*.держать тебя там, пока  не узнает, какое дитя родилось.*

Ну или смысл непонятен, надо его выразить как-то иначе.

Comment: Да, очень запутанное предложение), но мне нравится.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос к сложноподчиненному предикативному условию: Она перестала держать его там, потому что родилось то самое дитя.

Две пары основ подлежащее+сказуемое: она+собиралась и какое-дитя+не родится, разные вещи(условие и посылка) связанные через "пока" - поэтому ставится запятая.

Условие - она держит его там, пока.

Посылка - "какое дитя" родилось.

"какое дитя" родилось? - нет. Значит, условие не выполнено.

"какое дитя" родилось? - да. Значит, она должна его отпустить.

Для выполнения условия "она держит тебя там" необходимо чтобы "родилось то самое дитя (отсылка к следующему предложению, к "какое дитя?"->Христос придет второй раз, то есть "какое дитя" - это Антихрист)".

Comment: Это тема религиозной философии?  А я думала —  какого пола родится дитя, мальчик или девочка. К примеру,  для королевской семьи это важный вопрос о наследнике. А до второго пришествия Христа  —  просто фразеология, то есть очень долго ждать (о чём-нибудь далёком и неопределённом).

Comment: @Sharon не знаю какая философия, но какая-то религиозная дребедень.) Если бы не было "какое дитя не родится", а только потом про Христа, то было просто далекое время, а так это какие-то угрозы, странная фраза.